# Similarity Transformation when the Linear Operator is not written in the standard basis doesn’t lead to a Diagonal Matrix. Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization, normal-operator

Consider a diagonalizable linear operator $T$, and let $\{\alpha\}$ be the basis of eigenvectors of $T$. Let $\{\beta\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$ and let $\{\gamma\}$ be another arbitrary basis. Now the similarity transformation when the $T$ is written in standard orders basis  proceeds as follows -

\begin{equation}
S^{-1}[T]_\beta S =  [S]_\beta^\alpha [T]_\beta^\beta [S]_\alpha^\beta = [STS]_\alpha^\alpha........................(1)
\end{equation}

Equation $(1)$ leads to a diagonal representation of $T$.

Now consider the similarity transformation when $T$ is written in the basis $\{\gamma\}$. This proceeds as follows :

\begin{equation}
S’^{-1}[T]_\gamma S’=  [S’]_\gamma^\alpha [T]_\gamma^\gamma [S’]_\alpha^\gamma = [S’TS’]_\alpha^\alpha........................(2)
\end{equation}

*Equation $(2)$ doesn’t lead to a diagonal matrix.*

**The question is simple - why ?**

For e.g.:

Let $T(x,y) = (2x+y,11x+12y)$. In the standard basis this is $T = \begin{pmatrix}2 &1 \\ 11 & 12\end{pmatrix}$. The basis of eigenvectors is $[1,11],[-1,1]$ in which the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 13 &0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Let $B$ be a new basis, $\{[1,1],[1,0]\}$. Then in this basis one sees the matrix for $T$ is $M=\begin{pmatrix} 23 & 11 \\ -20 & -9 \end{pmatrix}$. Now, the change of basis from $B$ to the eigenbasis is the matrix $S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 11 & 1\end{pmatrix}^{(-1)} \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} = \frac 1{12}  \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ -10 &-11\end{pmatrix}$. Now, $S^{-1} MS$ should be diagonal but is not : both the off-diagonal entries is non-zero.

**Why does the Similarity Transformation not lead to a diagonal matrix when the the linear operator is written in a basis other than the standard ordered basis?**

**Why is the standard ordered basis special in getting a diagonal matrix using a similarity transformation?**

Comment: Made the edits, please check and makes sure this matches with our chat from earlier.

Comment: Explain your symbols. What does the expression $S^{-1}[T]_\beta S$ mean? If $S$ is a linear operator and $[T]_\beta$ is a matrix, they don't form a product. And what does $[T]_\beta$ mean? How is it different from $[T]_\beta^\beta$?

Comment: @user1551 $T$ is the linear operator, $[T]_\beta$ is its matrix representation. $S$ are the change of basis matrices. For $T:V->W$, I would represent the matrix for $T$ as $[T]_a^b $ where $\{a\}$ is basis for $V$ and $\{b\}$ is a basis for $V$. $[T]_\beta^\beta$ is the matrix representation for $T:V->V$ and $S^{-1}[T]_\beta S$ is the similarity transformation

Comment: @user1551 Note that in the above notation $[T]_\beta $ is the same as $[T]_\beta^\beta$

Comment: If $S$ is already a matrix, what do $[S]_\alpha^\beta$ and $STS$ in $(1)$ mean? You don't multiply a matrix ($S$) by a linear operator ($T$), do you? I have the impression that you are overloading the same symbol $S$ to mean different things. That's confusing.

Comment: @user1551 $[S]_\alpha^\beta $ **represents the change of basis matrix from the basis $\{\alpha\}$ to the basis $\{\beta\}$, whereas $S^{-1}$ which is being represented as $[S]_\beta^\alpha is the change of basis matrix from $\{\beta\}$ to ${\alpha\}$ basis. This notation is straight out from, Fridberg Insel Linear Algebra

Comment: The bottom-right element of $M$ should be $-9$, not $9$. The subsequent calculations are probably wrong because of this mistake.

Comment: @user1551 Corrected, thank you very much. It is still non-diagonal. For further checking  , $S^{-1}MS = \begin{pmatrix} -218 & -333 \\ 180 & 274\end{pmatrix}$, following [this Wolfram query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B2%2C1%5D%2C%5B-10%2C-11%5D%5D%5E%28-1%29+%5B%5B23%2C11%5D%2C%5B-20%2C-9%5D%5D+%5B%5B2%2C1%5D%2C%5B-10%2C-11%5D%5D). This matrix furthermore has the same trace and determinant as the diagonal matrix with entries 13,1, which tells me I must be right.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols you use don't make sense and they are very confusing.

When $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are bases of two finite-dimensional vector spaces $V$ and $W$ respectively and $T:V\to W$ is a linear map, the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to the bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is denoted by $[T]_\alpha^\beta$. Note that $T$ is a linear map, not a matrix, and $[T]_\alpha^\beta$ is not a linear map, but a matrix *representing* a linear map.

When one writes expressions like $[S]_\alpha^\beta,[STS]_\alpha^\alpha$ or $S^{-1}[T]_\beta S$, unless one overloads the same symbol to mean different things, $S$ should mean either a linear map or a matrix. However, if $S$ is a matrix, it doesn't make any sense to write $[S]_\alpha^\beta$ or $[STS]_\alpha^\alpha$. Similarly, if $S$ is a linear map, it doesn't make sense to write $S^{-1}[T]_\beta S$. The symbol $S$ in your equality $(1)$ thus have contradictory meanings.

A correct and clearer way to deal with matrix representations under changes of bases is to stick with the convention that the $T$ in $[T]_\alpha^\beta$ is a linear map. When $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are bases of the same vector space $V$, the change of basis matrix from $\alpha$ to $\beta$ is $[\operatorname{id}]_\alpha^\beta$ --- since we only change the basis of $V$ without mapping any vector in $V$ to a different vector, the linear map inside the pair of square brackets is the identity map $\operatorname{id}$, not some mysterious $S$. Given the matrix representation $[T]_\alpha^\alpha$ of a linear operator $T$ with respect to the basis $\alpha$, the matrix of $T$ with respect to another basis $\beta$ is obtained by
$$
[T]_\beta^\beta
=[\operatorname{id}\circ T\circ \operatorname{id}]_\beta^\beta
=[\operatorname{id}]_\alpha^\beta [T]_\alpha^\alpha [\operatorname{id}]_\beta^\alpha
=\left([\operatorname{id}]_\beta^\alpha\right)^{-1} [T]_\alpha^\alpha [\operatorname{id}]_\beta^\alpha.
$$

When $\beta$ is an eigenbasis for $T$, the matrix $[T]_\beta^\beta$ is diagonal. Hence $[T]_\alpha^\alpha=[\operatorname{id}]_\beta^\alpha[T]_\beta^\beta \left([\operatorname{id}]_\beta^\alpha\right)^{-1}$ is a diagonalisation of $[T]_\alpha^\alpha$. This is true regardless of whether $\alpha$ is the standard basis or not.

In your example, let $\alpha$ be the standard basis, $\beta$ be the eigenbasis from $T$ and $\gamma$ be the new basis. Then
$$
[\operatorname{id}]_\beta^\alpha=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 11&1},
[\operatorname{id}]_\gamma^\alpha=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&0}.
$$
Hence the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to $\gamma$ is
$$
[T]_\gamma^\gamma
=\left([\operatorname{id}]_\gamma^\alpha\right)^{-1} [T]_\alpha^\alpha [\operatorname{id}]_\gamma^\alpha
=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&0}^{-1}\pmatrix{2&1\\ 11&12}\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&0}
=\pmatrix{23&11\\ -20&-9}.
$$
The change-of-basis matrices from $\gamma$ to $\beta$ and from $\beta$ to $\gamma$ are given by
\begin{align}
[\operatorname{id}]_\gamma^\beta
&=[\operatorname{id}]_\alpha^\beta[\operatorname{id}]_\gamma^\alpha
=\left([\operatorname{id}]_\beta^\alpha\right)^{-1}[\operatorname{id}]_\gamma^\alpha
=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 11&1}^{-1}\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&0}
=\frac{1}{12}\pmatrix{2&1\\ -10&-11},\\
[\operatorname{id}]_\beta^\gamma
&=\left([\operatorname{id}]_\gamma^\beta\right)^{-1}
=\pmatrix{11&1\\ -10&-2}.
\end{align}
One can verify that the similarity transform
$$
[\operatorname{id}]_\gamma^\beta
[T]_\gamma^\gamma
[\operatorname{id}]_\beta^\gamma
=\frac{1}{12}\pmatrix{2&1\\ -10&-11}\pmatrix{23&11\\ -10&-9}\pmatrix{11&1\\ -10&-2}=\pmatrix{13&0\\ 0&1}
$$
indeed a diagonalises $[T]_\gamma^\gamma$.

Comment: So the issue must have been in the computation. In my case, I see the mistake : I confused the change of basis matrices. Thank you very much for the effort in verifying this case.